# Python code deletes the entirety of my csv document

Tags: python

does anyone know how to fix this issue. I'm trying to check the even rows for the phrase "Census 1850" anywhere in that row. If it finds that phrase in the row then it should keep the row and the row immediately above it. if it doesn't find it then it should delete that row and the row immediately above it. The dataset that I was using is:

[image]

(didn't paste in the other rows but there's more)

The code I was using was:

```
import csv

def scan_csv_file(file_path):
    """
    This function scans a CSV file and performs the following operations:
    - Scans the even rows for the phrase "Census 1850" anywhere in the row
    - If found, keeps that cell and deletes the cell above it
    - If not found, deletes that row and one row above it
    - Checks only the even rows for this
    
    Parameters:
    file_path (str): The path to the CSV file to be scanned
    
    Returns:
    None
    """
    try:
        # Open the CSV file
        with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
            # Read the CSV file
            csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
            # Create a list to store the rows to be written to a new file
            new_rows = []
            # Create a variable to keep track of the current row number
            row_num = 0
            # Initialize the new_row variable outside the loop
            new_row = []
            # Loop through each row in the CSV file
            for row in csv_reader:
                # Check if the row number is even
                if row_num % 2 == 0:
                    # Check if the phrase "Census 1850" is in the row
                    if "Census 1850" in ','.join(row):
                        # Keep the current cell and delete the cell above it
                        new_row = row[1:]
                    else:
                        # Delete the current row and the row above it
                        if len(new_rows) > 0:
                            new_rows.pop()
                            continue
                else:
                    # Keep the current row
                    new_row = row
                # Append the new row to the list of rows
                new_rows.append(new_row)
                # Increment the row number
                row_num += 1
        # Overwrite the existing CSV file with the new rows
        with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as file:
            csv_writer = csv.writer(file)
            csv_writer.writerows(new_rows)
        print("CSV file modified successfully.")
    except Exception as e:
        # Log the error
        print(f"Error: {e}")

# Provide the path to your CSV file
file_path = r"C:\Users\My Name\Downloads\tracing_the_land_2_test.csv"

scan_csv_file(file_path)
```

However, it just kept deleting everything in the document. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Open the file once at the start of the method. Each time you open the file in `w` mode, it will erase the previous contents and start anew. I also suggest writing to a temporary file first, and only when the full file is written, move it into the final location. See `shutil.move()` and `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile`. This way if you fail halfway through, you do not destroy any content you may wish to keep.

Comment: Why are you treating these data as CSV?

Answer (score 1):

The sample data shown in the question does not appear to be CSV in nature. It's just line-oriented text in pairs.

It may be feasible to read the entire contents into memory and process the data accordingly. However, using a temporary file is more flexible as the input file only needs to be read one line at a time.

For example:

```
import shutil

FILENAME = r'C:\Users\My Name\Downloads\tracing_the_land_2_test.csv'
TEMPNAME = f'{FILENAME}.tmp'

try:
    with open(FILENAME) as census, open(TEMPNAME, 'w') as temp:
        for lineno, line in enumerate(census):
            if (lineno % 2) != 0 and 'Census 1850' in line:
                temp.write(prev) # type: ignore
                temp.write(line)
            else:
                prev = line
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
else:
    shutil.move(TEMPNAME, FILENAME)
```

Comment: Would not do the move as a `finally`, only if no error is raised

Comment: @flakes If either of the open() calls fail then the shutil.move() would also fail so the net effect is that it doesn't really matter. However, it's probably worth noting if the temporary file was ever written to so I'll edit to allow for that

Comment: I think the semantics you're looking for are `try: ... else: ...` where `else` only executes if there was no exception during the `try` block :)

Comment: +1. For your previous comment, although file `open` probably would be handled appropriately, it is still possible for an individual `write` raise an exception. e.g. you run out of space on the file system, where in that case you could have half the writes finish however the move of the file succeed (disk space limitation vs inodes). I usually try to err on the side of caution with finally, assuming that anything in the block could cause errors (or if not now, maybe when new code is added or refactored, introducing possible side-effects).

Answer (score 0):

you pop() the rows which doesn't contain the statement you are searching for and consequently your total number of rows will change and the order which you visit each row change too. in other word, you don't necessarily visit each rows.
let me give you and scenario:
at the beginning of your code your file has 8 rows and when you start you check rows_number 2 and  pop the above rows. after that your file will have 6 rows and you visit rows_number 4 of new file which is row_number 6 of your former file.
some rows are skipped this way.
hope help you.

Comment: This shouldn't be a problem, because the loop iterates over `csv_reader`. It's not iterating over `new_rows`, which is the list that has items popped from it.

Answer (score 0):

I created a file containing the following data:

```
ggg
Census 1850 blah
ssss
Census 1850 blah
aaaa
Census 1850 blah
eeee
rrrrrr
ddddd
Census 1850 blah
fff
Census 1850 blah
ggg
Census 1850 blah
sadfadsfd
sdfdsfsd
hhhh
Census 1850 blah
```

The following code processes the data as desired:

```
import pandas as pd
file_path = 'census.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, header=None)
wanted_rows = df.loc[(df.index % 2 == 1) & df.loc[:, 0].str.contains('Census 1850'), 0]
previous_indices = [i - 1 for i in wanted_rows.index]
wanted_indices = list(wanted_rows.index) + previous_indices
df = df.loc[wanted_indices].sort_index()
```

Output:

```
                   0
0                ggg
1   Census 1850 blah
2               ssss
3   Census 1850 blah
4               aaaa
5   Census 1850 blah
8              ddddd
9   Census 1850 blah
10               fff
11  Census 1850 blah
12               ggg
13  Census 1850 blah
16              hhhh
17  Census 1850 blah
```

You can change the column name in `df.loc[:, 0]` from 0 to whatever you got. In case you have a header, then change `header=False` to `header=True`. Change the file name as required.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring this out. I had non-breaking space characters inside of the "census 1850" cells so it wouldn't read that correctly.